# How to resolve create MySQL 5.5.53 read replica with error InvalidParameterCombination, Status 400?

Tags: amazon-rds

Today I tried to create read replica for MySQL 5.5.53 RDS, it give me below error

> Cannot find version 5.5.53 for mysql (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code:
> 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterCombination;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create read replica in UI version did not worked. I tried there **[AWS cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/create-db-instance-read-replica.html)** mode to create

```
aws rds create-db-instance-read-replica --db-instance-identifier <read_replica_name> --source-db-instance-identifier <master-server-name> --db-instance-class <class-name> --availability-zone <zone> --no-multi-az --auto-minor-version-upgrade --no-publicly-accessible  --vpc-security-group-ids <vpc-id>
```

And it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error today when trying to load the "Modify" page for one of my RDS instances. I discovered that this happens when I navigate to the instance from the "Resources" tab in a CloudFormation stack, but not when I navigate to the instance from the "Instances" list in the RDS console. (The two paths do result in different URLs but what looks like the same page.)

Thought I'd add this in case it's what was behind your error message, or for someone else who searches and finds this question as I did.